# Subtract values in two textboxes in listview row

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Sorry about that... I am using an ASP.NET listview that can have one or many rows.  Here is the HTML that is generated for the listview itself.  I want to be able to subtract the two INPUTS named txtAmount and txtPayAmt from one another so that I can message the customer if they are getting ready to pay on an account that already has a zero balance.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 590" id=divBTUAccts>
    <TABLE style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #cc9966 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #cc9966 1px solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white; WIDTH: 100%; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; BORDER-TOP: #cc9966 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #cc9966 1px solid" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=4>
        <TBODY>
            <TR class=AccountTableHeader>
                <TH>&nbsp; </TH>
                <TH>Account / Address </TH>
                <TH>Due Date </TH>
                <TH>Payment Amount </TH>
                <TH>Recurring? </TH>
            </TR>
            <TR class=MainRowColor>
                <TD><INPUT id=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_BTUWeb_ContentPlaceHolder_CenterColumn_ListView_Accounts_ctrl0_chkAccount CHECKED type=checkbox name=ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody_BTUWeb$ContentPlaceHolder_CenterColumn$ListView_Accounts$ctrl0$chkAccount> </TD>
                <TD><SPAN id=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_BTUWeb_ContentPlaceHolder_CenterColumn_ListView_Accounts_ctrl0_lblAcct>2116280</SPAN>&nbsp;-&nbsp; <SPAN id=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_BTUWeb_ContentPlaceHolder_CenterColumn_ListView_Accounts_ctrl0_lblAddr>16177 WOODLAKE DR</SPAN> </TD>
                <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center"><SPAN id=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_BTUWeb_ContentPlaceHolder_CenterColumn_ListView_Accounts_ctrl0_lblDueDt>05/25/2011</SPAN> </TD>
                <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: right"><SPAN id=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_BTUWeb_ContentPlaceHolder_CenterColumn_ListView_Accounts_ctrl0_lblDollar>$</SPAN> <INPUT style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" id=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_BTUWeb_ContentPlaceHolder_CenterColumn_ListView_Accounts_ctrl0_txtAmount value=10.00 type=text name=ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody_BTUWeb$ContentPlaceHolder_CenterColumn$ListView_Accounts$ctrl0$txtAmount {95919BE0-C436-4eab-8083-096E94826667}="10.00"> </TD>
                <TD></TD>
                <TD style="DISPLAY: none"><INPUT style="DISPLAY: none" id=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_BTUWeb_ContentPlaceHolder_CenterColumn_ListView_Accounts_ctrl0_txtAmtDue value=0 type=text name=ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody_BTUWeb$ContentPlaceHolder_CenterColumn$ListView_Accounts$ctrl0$txtAmtDue {95919BE0-C436-4eab-8083-096E94826667}="0"> </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR class=AccountTableFooter>
                <TD>&nbsp; </TD>
                <TD>&nbsp; </TD>
                <TD>&nbsp; </TD>
                <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: right">&nbsp; </TD>
                <TD>&nbsp; </TD>
            </TR><!--End of ListView_Accounts-->
            <TR class=AccountTablePager align=middle>
                <TD colSpan=5><SPAN id=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_BTUWeb_ContentPlaceHolder_CenterColumn_DataPager1><SPAN>1</SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN> </TD>
            </TR>
        </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
</DIV>
```

I am new to using jQuery and so I throw myself on the mercy of you developers out there for help on this problem.  I need to iterate through one or many rows in a listview all the while subtracting the amount in one textbox in the row from another.  I have been trying to figure this out for a day now with no luck.  Please help!

Comment: Can you provide HTML? I'm not sure what element you are meaning with "listview" do you mean `<select>`?

Comment: Why don't you just use a normal HTML `<select>`, rather than this fancy ASP.net rubbish?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find control method for the ListViewItem to find your controls.  Cast the controls as a textbox then get the values.

However you may be better served by checking the Item on the ItemDatabound event to see if there is a zero balance then add a js onclick to the checkbox that if it is checked then hit them with the alert.